# return the highest level factor

Tags: r, refactoring, categories

I'm trying to work with an ordered categorical variable. It seems like the max min functions should work with the ordered categories, but it doesn't.

```
var<-factor(c("1","6","4","3","5","2"),levels=c("1","6","4","3","5","2"))
max(levels(var))
```

I'd like the code to return the very last factor level (2), but it returns the second (6). What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: 6 is the maximum. And you are asking for it. Maybe `tail`?

Comment: `levels(var)[max(as.numeric(var))]` returns `[1] "2"`. btw your factors are not ordered in the R sense.

Comment: 6 is the numerical maximum, but when I specify the order in the "levels" part of the command, I would assume that it would spit out the last level (2).

Comment: Using `max` on a character vector is not what you want to be doing. Look at `max(c("6", "66", "7"))`. It would be weird to you to know that it returns "7".

Comment: @Pierre Lafortune - How would I order the levels in the R sense?

Comment: @LyzandeR you deleted your answer

Comment: Pretend that instead of numbers the factor levels are MC,MA,MB,IN,F2,F1. There is an arbitrary order to those that is not alphabetical.

Comment: @PierreLafortune I have undeleted it. Initially I saw the OP is using `max(levels(var))` in his question and I thought he might wanted sth else. But now I kind of think this is what they want.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just specify the `ordered` argument in the `factor` function and then it will work. See following:

```
#set the ordered argument to TRUE, so that R understands the order of the levels
#and i.e. which one is min and which is max
var<-factor(c("1","6","4","3","5","2"),levels=c("1","6","4","3","5","2"), ordered=TRUE)

#and then
> max(var)
[1] 2
Levels: 1 < 6 < 4 < 3 < 5 < 2
```

Comment: wow this is surprising +1!  do you know where `max` is documented to work on factors?  I see that it says they are generic functions, but is there a `max.factor` or `max.ordered`...

Comment: @bunk I can't seem to find anything about `max` on the documentation but you can find info at `?factor`. Factors are essentially integers in the background and apparently if they are ordered then they get ordered integers assigned to their levels. This is how `max` understands which element is actually the max.

Comment: I'm reading about it now, if you look at `?Summary`.  I didn't even know this groupGeneric stuff existed :D

Comment: @bunk Yep it does :). And I dont think there is a `max.factor` or `max.ordered`.